# Angular Uncaught object adding urlRouterProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On my config function when I pass the param ".config(function($urlRouterProvider)" I got this error

```
Uncaught object angular.min.js:6
 (anonymous function) angular.min.js:6
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:34
q angular.min.js:7
f angular.min.js:33
Cb angular.min.js:37
d angular.min.js:18
fc angular.min.js:18
id angular.min.js:17
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:217
a angular.min.js:146
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:31
q angular.min.js:7
De.c angular.min.js:31
```

I've also downloaded the lastest version of angular and the route module.

Comment: This is a known issue for missing modules: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might have forgotten to include `ng-route` module in your app.

```
var app = angular.module('yourApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: @BlaShadow, can you post your code? Please create jsfiddle or plunkr to get more help.

Comment: I've put it work, I find another way to call the config method.

Comment: this happen to me and it was because i forgot the ng-app = 'something' on the html, maybe you missed that too

Comment: I've made some test and was this that solve my issue. Thanks.